# How do I change the load order of initializers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an initializer that loads configuration settings from a yaml file. I need to use these settings in other initializers. The settings are not being seen by the initializers that need them. What I think is happening is the settings are getting loaded too late. How do I guaranty that my configuration initializer gets loaded first? Is it un-rails like to have initializers depend on another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Rename the initializer to `01_name.rb`, that will force it to load alphabetically previously.

**Edit**

To quote the official [Rails Guide for configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) (thanks [zetetic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17410/zetetic) for the tip):

> If you have any ordering dependency in
>   your initializers, you can control the
>   load order by naming. For example,
>   01_critical.rb will be loaded before
>   02_normal.rb.

Comment: Well, I'm facing the exact same thing myself, and this is what I'm using. So I'll be waiting with you :)

Comment: I do the same, and it also applies to the seed-files: they are also sorted alphabetically. I am not aware of another explicit method to change the order.

Comment: This is the very technique suggested in the "Configuring Rails Applications" guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: doesn't seem like it would be too hard to override the initialize! method in application.rb https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb and the run_initializers method in initializable.rb https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/initializable.rb just do a custom sort or add your needed ones first then glob the others, and set the @run var.

Comment: A cool option would also be to handle initializers now css and js are how handled by the asset pipeline.  Rails could create initialize.rb which just had `//= require_tree .` by default.  This would do the loading how it currently works.  Then you could modify it the same way you modify application.js and application.css

Comment: @DanCaddigan -- Agreed, that would be very cool!  In the mean time, can someone elaborate on why the current approach is so "ugly"?  It forces you to state your intentions in file names, which is actually pretty cool IMO.

Comment: @IssacBetesh this is an "ugly" solution because it creates a ton on unnecessary work if you have to edit them around. Lets say you have 25 files in there, then add one that needs to run first. You make the new one 01, and have to bump the number of every other file. Or you could name it 001, or 0001 and so on. The config.before_initialize solution is much better.

Comment: This answer was written in 2011. In (early) 2015, it seems like this behaviour still works. I conclude that this is a *stable, reliable* method of achieving this result. +1

Comment: Is this still the preferred technique in Rails 4?

Comment: Well @Donato, if you follow the link to the Rails Guide, you'll find the exact same statement is still there. I don't know about preferred, but it's certainly still the one that's being recommended by the team.

Comment: The statement of the Rails Guide was changed. Now it says: "While Rails supports numbering of initializer file names for load ordering purposes, a better technique is to place any code that need to load in a specific order within the same file."

Answer (score 33):

Even though the guide recommends prepending the initializer filenames with numbers, that does seem ugly.  Another way is to utilize the provided initialization hooks.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events

E.g.

```
# application.rb

module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_initialize do
     # initialization code goes here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @Midwire Seems to be supported in Rails 4.2 as far as I can tell as well:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/configuring.html#initialization-events

Comment: @samjewell Yep, that appears to be the case though I've not tested it.

Comment: Seems to be available in 3.0.0 https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/Rails/Railtie/Configuration/before_initialize

Comment: This is the way. Rails 5.2+ still works great. And just for the record `Rails` is available here as well, but it runs before your initializers in `config/initializers`.

Answer (score 31):

Put the configuration code in config/environment.rb file, right after the first require statement, such as:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Load global configurations
CONFIG = Hashie::Mash.new YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "application.yml"))[Rails.env]

# Initialize the rails application
RailsSetup::Application.initialize!
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a require_relative to make sure one file is loaded first.

```
# aaa.rb
require_relative 'bbb'
# ... code using values from bbb.rb ...
```

Comment: That works, but in addition to running the required file at the time it is required, Rails will *again* run the file when it ordinarily would in the normal course of running initializers (effectively, in the order in which they appear in a directory listing).  So you would want to make sure that the file you are requiring does not do anything you would not want to be run more than once.  By example, if the required file initializes a constant, Rails would warning you that you are  re-initializing the constant.

Comment: @MarkSchneider Another example: if the file inserts an middleware with `#use`, the middleware would be inserted again. This may even break the application.

Comment: @MarkSchneider I'm trying to understand why would that happens anyway. file once required is no longer required again .. example create a test.rb open irb
require_relative 'test'
> true
require_relative 'test'
> false

Comment: @MarkSchneider I believe because Rails invokes the initializer again.

Comment: That is what we use to do, led us to lot of misunderstandings unfortunately. I really do not know why rails `load` in stead of `require` initializers... Anyway, -1 since this would have thrown me off

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way is to use `config/boot.rb`. Any settings required in prior for another initialiser to load can be loaded in `config/boot.rb`.

I was getting empty value for `SysconfigIngestion.config['google_oauth']` when called inside my initializer `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`. Shifting it to boot.rb did the job.

##### config/boot.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
...

require File.expand_path('config/initializers/sysconfig_loader.rb')
SysconfigLoader.init

require File.expand_path('config/initializers/cipher.rb')

if ENV['DOCKER'] == 'true'
    oauth = SysconfigLoader.config['google_oauth']
    ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'] ||= oauth['client_id']
    ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'] ||= Cipher.decrypt oauth['secret']
end
```

##### config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  ## Following did not work
  ## SysconfigLoader.init
  ## oauth = SysconfigLoader.config['google_oauth']
  ## puts oauth['secret'].nil? # true

  ## But boot.rb successfully loaded the required values into ENV variables
  ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'].nil? ? puts("Missing oauth secret!") : puts("Found oauth secret :)")

  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], {}  
end
```

Application prints `Found oauth secret :)` on startup!!

Answer (score 0):

I just released a gem named [ordered_initializers](https://github.com/boccarab/ordered_initializers) that allows you to set the order in which you want your initializers to load, independently of their name, using a yml file.

Hope it could help. Feedbacks are welcome :)