# Rails 3 / Setting Custom Environment Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a rails application that assigns one value to a variable when the environment is the development environment, and another value to that same variable when the environment is the production environment.  I want to specify both values in my code (hardwired), and have rails know which value to assign to the variable based on which environment is running.  How do I do this?

In case it is important, I later access that variable and return its value in a class method of a model.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this with initializers.

```
# config/initializers/configuration.rb
class Configuration
  class << self
    attr_accessor :json_url
  end
end

# config/environments/development.rb
#  Put this inside the ______::Application.configure do block
config.after_initialize do
  Configuration.json_url = 'http://test.domain.com'
end

# config/environments/production.rb
#  Put this inside the ______::Application.configure do block
config.after_initialize do
  Configuration.json_url = 'http://www.domain.com'
end
```

Then in your application, call the variable Configuration.json_url

```
# app/controller/listings_controller.rb
def grab_json
  json_path = "#{Configuration.json_url}/path/to/json"
end
```

When you're running in development mode, this will hit the http://test.domain.com URL.

When you're running in production mode, this will hit the http://www.domain.com URL.

Comment: Any chance this is broken in 3.1?  Worked like a charm in my 3.0 app, now getting 
NoMethodError (undefined method 'test_conf' for ActiveSupport::Configurable::Configuration:Class):

Comment: # config/application.rb
class Application < Rails::Application
    attr_accessor :json_url

Comment: There is a much better way to do this with Rails 3+.  You can use the existing config to create config.json_url = '...'

I explained it further on http://jasonnoble.org/2011/12/updated-rails3-custom-environment-variables.html

Comment: This can be more easily managed by doing it with a .yml file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648620/setting-environment-variables-in-rails-3-devise-omniauth

Answer (score 15):

I like to store settings in YAML. To have different settings based on the environment, with defaults, you can have an initializer file (say `config/initializers/application_config.rb`) like this:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/application_config.yml")[Rails.env]
```

…and then in `config/application_config.yml` :

```
defaults: &defaults
    my_setting: "foobar"

development:
    # add stuff here to override defaults.
    <<: *defaults

test:
    <<: *defaults

production:
    # add stuff here to override defaults.
    <<: *defaults
```

…then, pull out the settings with `APP_CONFIG[:my_setting]`

Comment: How can you then use the "APP_CONFIG" in the code? I get an error : uninitialized constant MyController::APP_CONFIG

Comment: @Jojje, restart application. See dedicated railscast if you have any further questions http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file. Also symbol keys doesn't work for me. `APP_CONFIG['my_setting']` — this is how you read setting.

Comment: I needed this config in other initializers, so I ended up using the `YAML.load_file(...)` line within `config/environment.rb`, just before the `Application.initialize!` line.  (via [Tyler Long](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11054390/361609))

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Yettings gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/yettings) in Rails 3.2, which allows me to store my application variables in `config/yettings.yml` like so:

```
defaults: &defaults
  api_key: asdf12345lkj
  some_number: 999
  an_erb_yetting: <%= "erb stuff works" %>
  some_array:
    - element1
    - element2

development:
  <<: *defaults
  api_key: api key for dev

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

And access them like this:

```
#/your_rails_app/config/yetting.yml in production
Yetting.some_number #=> 999
Yetting.api_key #=> "asdf12345lkj"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find out the environment like this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Rails.env
  => "development"
```

Store the value in a global variable in your `config/application.rb` for example:

```
$foo = "something"
```

You could also assign the variable in your `config/environments/` files instead of deciding based ond `Rails.env` in `application.rb`. Depends on your situation.