# Ruby on Rails use of environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use in my code (in views as well) variables like:

```
ENV['SERVER_URL1']
```

And want them to be different for diffident environments (prod, dev, test)

1. Were and how should I set them up?
2. Is this (using ENV vars) a right way to configure application for different  environments?
3. about `ENV['SERVER_URL']` - is it a standard variable? When does it becomes available.

I tried to set in different parts of application (application.rb, development.rb)

```
ENV['SERVER_URL1'] = 'http://localhost:4000/'
```

but it seems not to work.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800028/rails-3-setting-custom-environment-variables). Do you really need them to be environment variables?

Comment: Well I want this variables to be different for local dev and prod heroku deploy, on heroku I can add ENV variables using config:add, but I don't know how to accomplish this task in my local dev environment.

Comment: Right, so you'd check for the environment in the initializer, and set appropriately.

Comment: I inserted to application.erb: ENV['SERVER_URL1'] = 'http://localhost:4000/path' but this value is not available in app. The same I did in development.rb

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? They don't do it like that. That's why I asked if you needed them to *specifically* be environment variables.

Comment: Yes, I've read, thanks for the link. But is not it possible to accomplish using ENV variables without custom Configuration class? Or I just don't understand what ENV variables for?

Comment: They're for whatever you want, I just don't yet know why they'd be preferred over initializer-based code in this usecase, which is why I've asked.

Comment: Ok it seems I got it. BTW one more newbie question: how to make this Configuration.propery avaliable for using in erb views?

Comment: Should just be available, although see the link regarding Rails 3.1. See the other answer in that link regarding the use of globals as an alternative, although I guess I'd avoid that, but that might just be a personal preference.

Comment: When I try to use it in in my view: <%= Configuration.server_url %> there the error occurs: uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Configuration

Comment: Aaaand what version of Rails are you using? Could also expose it as a controller variable if it's not automagically available.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3 rails 3.1.3, ok I'll try thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When using Rails 4.1+, the new and preferred way to set ENV variables is to use the `config/secrets.yml` file.

Here is an excerpt from the [4.1 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml)

> The secrets added to this file are accessible via Rails.application.secrets. For example, with the following config/secrets.yml:
>
> ```
> development:
>   secret_key_base: 3b7cd727ee24e8444053437c36cc66c3
>   some_api_key: SOMEKEY
> ```
>
> Rails.application.secrets.some_api_key returns SOMEKEY in the development environment.
>
> See the Upgrading Ruby on Rails guide on how to migrate existing applications to use this feature.

So you should set:

```
development:
  SERVER_URL1: http://localhost:4000
production:
  SERVER_URL1: http://my-domain.com
```