# Setting Environment Variables in Rails 3 (Devise + Omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables, omniauth, railscasts

I've been trying to figure out how Ryan Bates, in his [Facebook Authentication screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication),  is setting the following "FACEBOOK_APP_ID" and "FACEBOOK_SECRET" environment variables.

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
```

There are similar-ish questions around, but no answers that I've been able to get to work on Rails 3.2.1.

**UPDATE:**

As of May 2013, my preferred way to handle ENV variables is via the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You could take a look at [the comments](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=comments):

You can either set environment variables directly on the shell where you are starting your server:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID=12345 FACEBOOK_SECRET=abcdef rails server
```

Or (rather hacky), you could set them in your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] = "12345";
ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'] = "abcdef";
```

### An alternative way

However I would do neither. I would create a config file (say `config/facebook.yml`) which holds the corresponding values for every environment. And then load this as a constant in an initializer:

#### `config/facebook.yml`

```
development:
  app_id: 12345
  secret: abcdef

test:
  app_id: 12345
  secret: abcdef

production:
  app_id: 23456
  secret: bcdefg
```

#### `config/initializers/facebook.rb`

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

Then replace `ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']` in your code by `FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id']` and `ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']` by `FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret']`.

Comment: awesome - works for me. and then place facebook.yml in .gitignore - correct? also, one caveat - if using the variable in another initializer (as I am with devise.rb), make sure you rename your facebook.rb to come alphabetically before the file you need the variables in. In my case, I had to rename facebook.rb to config_facebook.rb in order for it to be loaded before devise.rb

Comment: just be aware that the order of that the initializers load is alphabetical. So if you need the config in another inititializer you will have to name the facebook.rb something like 01_facebook.rb (not too pretty - but works)

Comment: Any advice about whether to put the YAML file/Foreman .env into Git or to ignore it? I'd like to deploy to Heroku, but I'd also like to be able to publish my code on Github, so for one I'd need it checked in, the other I'd need it ignored.

Comment: Maybe create two separate branches, push one to github and the other one to Heroku?

Comment: Nitpicking: shouldn't `config/initializer/facebook.rb` be `config/initializers/facebook.rb` with an 's'?

Answer (score 29):

There are several options:

- Set the environment variables from the command line:

  ```
  export FACEBOOK_APP_ID=your_app_id
  export FACEBOOK_SECRET=your_secret
  ```

  You can put the above lines in your `~/.bashrc`
- Set the environment variables when running `rails s`:

  ```
  FACEBOOK_APP_ID=your_app_id FACEBOOK_SECRET=your_secret rails s
  ```
- Create a [`.env`](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#ENVIRONMENT) file with:

  ```
  FACEBOOK_APP_ID=your_app_id
  FACEBOOK_SECRET=your_secret
  ```

  and use either [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) (starting your app with `foreman start`) or the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem.

Comment: Foreman is the solution recommended by Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), that has commands to set them for the production env. Note that you should not commit the .env file on your Version Control. Consider a README explaining how to set it up.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another idea.  Define the keys and values in `provider.yml` file, as suggested above.  Then put this in your `environment.rb` (before the call to `Application.initialize!`):

```
YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/provider.yml")[::Rails.env].each {|k,v| ENV[k] = v }
```

Then these environment variables can be referenced in the `omniauth` initializer without any ordering dependency among intializers.

Comment: Is it invented by you or has it an authoritative source?

Comment: It's what i came up with after looking at some of the other solutions.

Comment: I like it.  It's concise (DRY) and secure.