# Devise + Omniauth Facebook Error: Oauth Exception Code 101

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I've looked at a bunch of the responses to Oauth 101 errors to try to troubleshoot, but I still keep getting this error:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Error validating application. Invalid application ID.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 101
}
}
```

The FB application ID matches the one that was given to me...so I don't really know what's up.

I followed directions from: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Here's a link to my repo: https://github.com/margotungsten/splurgeorsave

I should also say--I input the ID and Secret given to me by FB into both the devise.rb and omniauth.rb files and it still didn't work.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you make ENV variables? Where did you put the ID, secret and how did you save them? Also maybe putting them in devise also is causing an error.

Here's a good post for how to save them: [Setting Environment Variables in Rails 3 (Devise + Omniauth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648620/setting-environment-variables-in-rails-3-devise-omniauth)

Comment: railscasts has a good tutorial on this also. Just remember to set the environment variables somewhere else as in the last link I put in. railscast #360: http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `omniauth.rb` when configuring Omniauth with Devise. Remove it and try again.