# Error with Oauth token not redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I can't find my production ID and my production API secret. I can only find the developer ones. Am I supposed to submit for review first? My OAuth is all set up.

I also have my YML  So do I submit first and I will get this second ID? This has been my problem all day long. Thanks.

It looks like this:

```
Development:
facebook_api_key:
facebook_api_secret:

Production: 
facebook_api_key:
facebook_api_secret:
```

I tried adding my ID and secret for both of them even though it was only on dev! Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your problem has nothing to do with oauth. It is about how to setup **secret variables** between different environments.

I use [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem to handle this kind of variables:

First, add figaro in your Gemfile.

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'figaro'
```

Setup variables in config/applicaiton.yml. (I usually use UPPER CASE for these variables)

*config/application.yml*

```
development:
  FB_KEY: your_fb_key_for_development
  FB_SECRET: your_fb_secret_for_development

production: 
  FB_KEY: your_fb_key_for_production
  FB_SECRET: your_fb_secret_for_production
```

And use ENV to get variables where you want,

*config/initializers/devise.rb*

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...
  # Onmi configurations
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FB_KEY'], ENV['FB_SECRET']
  # ...
end
```

If you want to do it without any gem, please see:
[stackoverflow - Setting Environment Variables in Rails 3 (Devise + Omniauth)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11648620/232710)