# Ruby on Rails environment variable for development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables

Just a quick question to which I couldn't find an answer on stackoverflow.

If it is easy to have environment variable for staging and production (on heroku for example), how can I set environment variable for my localhost (development environment)? (I am on a mac)

As of today I hardcode my api credential for development environment and I don't feel comfortable with that.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648620/setting-environment-variables-in-rails-3-devise-omniauth?

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but it doesn't fits my needs. Sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) is intended to be used in development:

Add your application configuration to your `.env` file in the root of your project.

```
S3_BUCKET=YOURS3BUCKET
SECRET_KEY=YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE
```

You may also add export in front of each line so you can source the file in bash.
in `.bashrc`

```
export S3_BUCKET=YOURS3BUCKET
export SECRET_KEY=YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE
```

Then access in rails app `ENV['S3_BUCKET']`

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are best placed in your `.bash_profile` file which lives in your home directory on the Mac: `/Users/you/.bash_profile`. Open that file and add something like this to the end of it:

```
export MY_ENV_VAR=my_env_value
```

or

```
export MY_ENV_VAR="a string with spaces in it"
```

[export](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/exporth.html) is a shell command that sets environment variables. Your `.bash_profile` is a bash script that runs every time you open a new shell session (open a terminal window) and therefore your `export` commands will run and set the env vars.

Then they will be available in the `ENV` constant when you're in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/Users/your_user_name/.bash_profile` and add there:

```
export RAILS_ENV=development
```