# How to set system variable (e.g $PYTHONPATH), when calling bash command from Rails?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, linux, bash

I have a rails 4 app on AWS EC2 Ubuntu. It will call a python program using backticks:

```
    pyresult = `python /path/to/abc.py`
```

The python programe works perfect on my local dev. But it **failed** on the production server, with no error. (pyresult is empty)

**I've debugged for long time, and found a possible cause: $PYTHONPATH**

On local, i have the follow in my .bashrc, as the python program asked to add:

```
    export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

On server, i also added them in .bashrc on server. But run `echo $PYTHONPATH` in my app gives me empty string.

Then I added explicitly in my rails app,

```
    `export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"`
    pyresult = `python /path/to/abc.py`
```

but $PYTHONPATH is still empty. and calling python program still failed with no error.

Is it correct to guess the missing $PYTHONPATH caused the issue? if yes, how to solve the problem? Thanks for helping.(sorry i'm new to linux and not familiar with python)

Comment: This may be answered in [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11648620/1563512) stackoverflow answer. Did you try `ENV['PYTHONPATH'] = "/some/path:/some/otherpath";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Open4 gem to run the command, I found the rootcause is paython programe can't find the lib, which is installed via setup.py. So it's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Linux doesn't have system variables, only environment variables, which are only inherited by child processes. This line

```
`export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"`
```

only sets `PYTHONPATH` for the subshell started by the backquotes (and any processes started from that subshell). Once the shell exists, the setting for `PYTHONPATH` is gone.

You need to use whatever facility Ruby has for modifying the environment of the current process, which I gather (as someone who doesn't use Ruby) is

```
ENV['PYTHONPATH'] = '...'
```

Then the shell started by

```
pyresult = `python /path/to/abc.py`
```

will inherit its `PYTHONPATH` value from the current Ruby process.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried but it's not working. ENV[] is for ruby app but not the subshell started by the backticks.

Comment: In the shell, you should simply be able to access `$PYTHONPATH` as a variable. If you expect to change `PYTHONPATH` in the subshell *and* see that change in the Ruby app, that's impossible.

Comment: Hi Chepner, I've used spawn({"PYTHONPATH"=>"/my/path"},command}) to include PYTHONPATH in the subshell, and it will have PYTHONPATH as the environment variable. But somehow it's still not working. Looks some other issue =,= Tks for helping.