# Rails: OAuth::Unauthorized 401 Authorization Required using OmniAuth-Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth

I have implemented several different strategies found in StackOverFlow, but so far, none seem to affect the error being thrown:

`OAuth::Unauthorized`
`401 Authorization Required`

I am following [Ryan Bates' RC #241](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised?autoplay=true) and get to the point where I click "Sign-in with Twitter" and I get the error.  I went ahead and added the response route to the `routes.rb` file as listed here:

**`routes.rb`:**

```
match 'auth/twitter/callback', to: 'user#update'
```

thinking that the error might be caused from the callback function.  Same error.  A look at my `dev.log` shows this:

```
Started GET "/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-16 18:52:08 -0600
(twitter) Request phase initiated.

OAuth::Unauthorized (401 Authorization Required):
oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:29:in `request_phase'
omniauth-twitter (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:60:in `request_phase'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:215:in `request_call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:183:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
...
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

So I know the issue is with the authentication with Twitter going out.  Must be the KEY and SECRET, right?

Now, I have put the KEY and SECRET in as ENV[] variables, as direct strings to the `environment/development.rb` file, taken out the "ENV[]" variables, etc., as per suggestions found all over Stack.

My KEY and SECRET now reside in a custom configuration as discussed [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648620/setting-environment-variables-in-rails-3-devise-omniauth)

**`config/initializers/social_media.rb:`**

```
TWITTER_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/twitter.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

The `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` file:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, TWITTER_CONFIG['app_id'], TWITTER_CONFIG['secret']
end
```

Any ideas on the `ActionController: Exception caught OAuth::Unauthorized - 401 Authorization Required`?  This is probably a Noob error, but my Google-Fu is just Google-F'ed right now...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

After a night of tearing my hair out, I took at look at the callback URL on [Twitter developer console](http://dev.twitter.com).

Save yourselves some trouble and don't forget to set this.  It's not mentioned directly in the RailsCast, although Ryan does briefly pass over it.

When you set the callback URL, don't just put `//localhost:3000` it won't work.  Instead use:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Comment: Or you can use `lvh.me:3000` which resolves to 127.0.0.1

Comment: If you are using the 'sorcery' gem instead, there is a bug - see this solution: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/540#issuecomment-65752910

Comment: this was a lifesaver. I am using the RailsApp tutorials, and it was not very clear on this part.

Comment: It worked. But do I have to change it back to my domain later?

Comment: In my case callback URL was specified but my source web-app was using [oauth dynamic setup](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase) and required a custom callback url to be passed. But in my twitter settings I checked the option `Enable Callback Locking` (as it is mentioned as recommended by Twitter) and I started receiving this 401 error. I unchecked the option `Enable Callback Locking`  and the auth started working.

Comment: I figured out the cause by printing the oauth response body in method `OAuth::Consumer#token_request(http_method, path, token = nil, request_options = {}, *arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when working on a Rails 6 application with [omniauth-twitter](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-twitter) and [devise](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-twitter) gems

I had added the `API Key` and the `API Secret Key` to my **Rails 6** application, but when I try to test the Twitter Authentication, I run into the error below:

```
OAuth::Unauthorized 401 Authorization Required
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

I added the following Callback URLs to my Twitter developer account:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter
http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/twitter
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/twitter/callback
```

**Note**: Replace `localhost:3000` with your actual `host`. Also, the **routes** used for the callback URLs should match the ones that were set up in your application.

**Resources**: [How to Sign in with Twitter using Devise, Omniauth, and Ruby on Rails](https://web-crunch.com/posts/sign-in-with-twitter-using-devise-omniauth-ruby-on-rails)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**