# Trying to configure environment variables using fb app_id and app_secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth-facebook

I am following rails  cast #85 [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file?autoplay=true) and the marked correct answer on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648620/setting-environment-variables-in-rails-3-devise-omniauth#comment20518935).

I am trying to use facebook "app_id" and "app_secret" to set as environment variables in rails.

my code is:

initializers/facebook.rb

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

config/facebook.yml

```
development:
app_id: abcdefg
app_secret: 123456
production:
app_id: abcdefg
app_secret: 123456
```

initializers/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['abcdefg'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['123456'], {:client_options =>   {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

When I set the environment variables in front of the app_id and app_secret ie FACEBOOK_CONFIG when I try login through facebook it returns a "app_id parameter is required" message. So this way is not working. I am wondering if there is some code missing or someone can see something I am doing wrong the environment variables are not being processed through facebook (where they were before without any ENV variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `rails console` try it

***edit***

```
require 'yaml'
yaml = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path("#{Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml"))
puts yaml
```

***edit 2 ***

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

change to:

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path("#{Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml"))[::Rails.env]
```

Comment: When I try and do require 'yaml' in rails console it returns a false value? The others I am not to sure what is happening there.

Comment: Is ok about returns false. Show me the puts returns

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `yaml' for main:Object
        from (irb):1 .... then the list of gems that failed to initialize

Comment: ok so now is giving me the results `=> {"development"=>{"app_id"=>abcdefg, "app_secret"=>"123456"}, "production"=>{"app_id"=>abcdefg, "app_secret"=>"123456"}}`

Comment: I wish it did for some reason still getting the same response "the parameter app_id is required" I may have to try something else maybe the figaro gem, can you see whats wrong?

Comment: sorry the penny dropped, i had had the app_id and app_secret still set as the 'actual' app id and secret so the FACEBOOK_CONFIG constant was not registering.Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Any time.