# Rails 5 custom initializer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a file called `frontend_configuration.rb` which looks like this:

```
class FrontEndConfiguration
  class << self
    attr_accessor :base_url
  end
end
```

In my `development` config, I have a line:

```
FrontEndConfiguration.base_url = "http://localhost:4200"
```

When I try to run my rails server, it gives me an error saying:

```
uninitialized constant FrontEndConfiguration (NameError)
```

I am following this Stackoverflow answer here: [Rails 3 / Setting Custom Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800028/rails-3-setting-custom-environment-variables)

Any ideas why Rails isn't detecting my custom initializer?

I am using Rails 5 API only mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```yaml
# config/frontend.yml:
production:
  environment: production
  base_url: http://your_url
  .
  .
  .
development:
  environment: sandbox
  base_url: http://your_url
  .
  .
  .
```

```rb
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.frontend = config_for(:frontend)
  end
end
```

And now,

```
Rails.configuration.frontend['base_url'] 
# => production_base_url or development_base_url
```

Comment: Is this the recommended way of doing it in Rails 5 now? It certainly works for what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Zhang yes it is.See the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration)