# Adding to Rails.application.config before initializers run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to inject a custom property (hash map) into my `Rails.application.config`. It seems that the way to do it is simply to assign a new variable in `environment.rb`:

`Rails.application.config.feature_map = { :email => true }`

I need to access this map through various places in my application, like the user model, controllers, and rake tasks.

Other gems, like `devise`, also need access to this. The problem is that adding it to `environment.rb` seems to be too early in the application life-cycle.

I have code in `initializers/devise.rb` like this:

`if Rails.application.config.feature_map[:email] = true`

The server complains that this field doesn't exist.

I also use it to add additional validation in my user model:

`if Rails.application.config.feature_map.enabled?(:username)

    validates_length_of :username, :in => 3..50`

I also get a runtime error here about `undefined feature Rails.application.config.feature_map`

Where can I move this so that I can access it as early as in initializers and in my model class? I tried moving it into a new `initializers/feature_map.rb` file, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in config/application.rb:

```
module MyRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.feature_map = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
    config.feature_map.email = true
  end
end
```

Anything you set in there will be default for all environments, but can be overridden per environment in config/environments/*.rb.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. `FeatureMap` is a class in `lib` for me, so I have to use `require "#{config.root}/lib/feature_map"`. It works great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gems like Figaro and .env will help you load up your config even before the loading of initializer.rb

Unless there is a strong reason that you wouldn't wanna use environment variables, I would recommend using either of those gems since they are the recommended way of adding your custom configs.

Comment: I prefer a simpler approach over adding more gems. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** See Jimmy Cuadra's answer above, which I ended up going with.

I found an alternative solution: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779788/210780) to manipulate the order of initializers.

I can rename my initializer to `00_feature_map.rb` and it loads first.